# Passing textarea line breaks to the server

Tags: html

I am facing a peculiar problem. The scenario is, a user types into my `textarea` which has 10 columns and 20 rows. Once the user types till the 10th column, the text seems to wrapped to the next row. But in actual it does not happen.

For example in user types "Hi this is a." the `a` wraps to next line, but when data is passed to backend it is passed as a single line. I want the data to be passed with the formatting being applied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The textarea only wraps for convenience to the writer.  It's passed as a single string because it is a single string.  In some browsers, if you type a long string with no spaces, it will show a horizontal scroll bar instead of wrapping.

Anyway, the solution is to parse the data yourself.  If it has 10 columns and each column is 1 character, then you should line break after every 10 characters without separating words.  The specific method for doing this depends a lot depending on what programming language you are using.

Comment: thank you for reply tandu. i thought there would be some pre defined method to achieve this.